# [NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I'm trying to fill a table view with some data from an array . The array is populated but when i run the app i get this error : reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I searched for similar questions , but no one was the right for me. I don't use the lenght function and my app is crashing on : cell.textLabel.text = [self.currentDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

quizViewController.m

```
- (void)passDataForward
{
    ScoreViewController *secondViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"score"];

    secondViewController.data =self.scoreLabel.text;
    secondViewController.delegate = self;

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [highScores insertObject:self.scoreLabel.text atIndex:highScores.count];

    NSData *currentDate =[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YYYY                        HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

    [data insertObject:dateString atIndex:data.count];



    NSMutableArray *scorearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"high_scoresarray"]];

     NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"data_score"]];

    [scorearray addObject:highScores];
    [dataArray addObject:data];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:scorearray forKey:@"high_scoresarray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataArray forKey:@"data_score"];


    secondViewController.test=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: scorearray];
    secondViewController.currentDate=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: dataArray];

    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {

     }];
}
```

ScoreViewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.currentDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you NSLog(@"%@",self.currentDate} in your ScoreViewController's viewDidLoad method, what is in your field? Does it crash there as well? Btw I'm not sure if there are typos in your code, but this line NSData *currentDate =[NSDate date]; , NSData and NSDate?

Comment: And is your data there? Your variables are really weird named, like I would expect self.currentDate to be NSDate, but it seems to be array.. Maybe that is problem - in line cell.textLabel.text = [self.currentDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Can you confirm, that self.currentDate is indeed an array? (your cellForRow method from ScoreViewController)

Comment: self.currentDate is an array and my data are there when i NSLog(@"%@",self.currentDate}

Comment: Ok please try to insert this - if([self.currentDate isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { } before the line it is crashing and insert breakpoint there (between {}). Then try it, if it stops there. I still think that self.currentDate is not an array :)

Comment: i changed some things . Now i have  NSArray *scorearray2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"high_scoresarray"];
    NSArray *dataArray2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"data_score"];
    if([scorearray2 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [scorearray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }    but it's still crashing :  reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (4) beyond bounds (4)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aris is right. 
`self.currentDate` returns an `NSArray`. And that is caused by:

```
[scorearray addObject:highScores];
[dataArray addObject:data];
```

Where you are adding one array as the only item to the array `scorearray` and `dataArray` respectively. You do not add a bunch of strings, which I assume are stored within `highScores` and `data`. 
Replace it with

```
[scorearray addObjectsFromArray:highScores];
[dataArray addObjectsFromArray:data];
```

That should add the contents of `highScores` and `data` to `scorearray` and `dataarray`.

Comment: Erase the app from the simulator or device first. Status Quo is that your user preferences are corrupted already. Start from scratch with clean data and go for the `addObjectsFromArray`. `addObject` is certainly wrong unless you want to add an array instead of a number of strings.

Answer (score 5):

The error means that this line:

```
[self.currentDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

returns an Array instead of an NSString. Which means that

```
self.currentDate
```

contains NSArray objects and not NSString objects.

Comment: And you can confirm that because: `secondViewController.currentDate=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: dataArray];` and `[dataArray addObject:data];` and `[data insertObject:dateString atIndex:data.count];`

Comment: i changed :    self.scorearray2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"high_scoresarray"];  and in cellForRowAtIndexPath     cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  but it's not working.

Comment: (lldb) po self.scorearray2
<__NSCFArray 0xd214940>(
<__NSCFArray 0xd215860>(
0
)